# Configure Android studio for local builds

Tags: android, nativescript, tns

I am setting up android studio to build and run an android app.

After running `tns build android --bundle`

I get the following error message

```
Error executing Static Binding Generator: Class not found android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener
Detailed log here: /Users/Rothacker/Desktop/desktop folder/workspace/switchmaven/pngpigs-app/platforms/android/build-tools/runSbg.log

Command ./gradlew failed with exit code 1
```

**Environment**

Node version is`v12.16.1`

Java version:

`openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_242-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)`

My ENV variables are:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_AVD_HOME
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=/Users/$USER/.android/avd
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=/Users/$USER/.android/avd
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk
```

Comment: Does the build work outside of this environment? can you post the "Detailed log" content mentioned on the logs?

Comment: Which version of {N} & plugin you are using?